# gnu coreutils split verbose flushed?

Tags: file-management, gnu, coreutils

When using the GNU coreutils `split` command with verbose mode, how can I make the lines that appear in the STDOUT be flushed with respect to the time when the file has finally been created?

Fore example, running it like this:

```
~/coreutils/bin/split --verbose -d -u -l 10000000 1>out & tail -f out
creating file `x00'
creating file `x01'
creating file `x02'
[...]
```

I would have expected the line `creating file 'x00'` to have appeared in file `out` after the file has been completely written, but instead, it seems like nothing is written into `out` until the whole file has been finally processed. Is there a way to change this behavior?

Comment: I think all GNU coreutils use output buffering, so they won't output anything until the buffer is filled or earlier if the output is an interactive terminal.

Comment: output to stdout is buffered, stderr is not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, old versions of GNU coreutils (before 7.5) don't have an easy workaround (as far as I know), but newer versions (since 7.5) have a **stdbuf** command you can use to force split (or any other coreutil program) to immediately print its output. In your case, you can use:

```
~/coreutils/bin/stdbuf -o0 ~/coreutils/bin/split --verbose -d -u -l 10000000 1>out & tail -f out
```

That will run split with output buffering disabled.

Please note the -u option (unbuffered) in split does not affect the message printing, only the data it's splitting (it feels slower if you disable that buffering).

Information about stdbuf: http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/stdbuf-invocation.html

For an alternative when using older coreutils versions, check this solution using command **unbuffer** from the package expect (tcl): https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/25372/turn-off-buffering-in-pipe